# Can you fake a join in Mongo aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I have documents of the form

```javascript
members:
    {
    _id:ObjectId("xxx"),
    name:"John",
    branch:ObjectId("yyy")
    }

branches:
    {
    _id:ObjectId("yyy"),
    name:"Branch A"
    }
```

I want to report on the number of people in each branch.  A straight $group pipeline does this but I can only get it to report back the branch _id and then convert it in my code.  I would like to do something like:

```javascript
db.members.aggregate(
    {$group:{_id:db.branches.findOne(
        {_id:"$branch"},
        {name:1}).name,count:{$sum:1}}})
```

Which appears not to work.  Is there something along those lines that does work?

Comment: MongoDb does not yet possess the ability to do subqueries which would make this possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can iterate over the result of the aggregation and query for the name. In the mongo shell this would look like:

```
db.members.aggregate(
    { $group: { _id: "$branch", count: { $sum: 1 } }
}).result.forEach(function(val, idx) {
    var branch = db.branches.findOne( { _id: val._id.$id } );
    val.name = branch.name;
    printjson(val);
 })
```

If you your using a language driver, do the aggregate and iterate there over the result and do a separate query for the branch name. This is a good example, why schema design is necessary in MongoDB too. I would recommend to denormalize and put the branch name directly into the member object.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the MongoDB Aggregation docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) there's no direct equivalent for SQL's `JOIN`, which would allow aggregating data from multiple collections in a single query.

Answer (score -2):

I maybe have a solution:

```
db.members.aggregate(
    {$group:{_id:db.branches.findOne(
    {_id:this.branch},
    {name:1}).name,count:{$sum:1}}})
```